# file handling not displaying data accordingly

Tags: php, html

I have the below php file. When i try to run this file, nothing is getting displayed

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    $myfile = fopen("1.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fgetss($myfile,149,"<td>,</td>");
    fclose($myfile);
    ?>
</body>
```

The 149th line of my 1. txt file is

```
<td>Mfg of Textile Readymade Garments</td>
```

Comment: what is the extension of the file? .php pr .html? and from where you are trying to run it?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. check your 1.txt file have permission to read and write and also check the path of the file.

Comment: `149` is the number of bytes to read from the current position in the file. and not the line number to read

Comment: If you want to read line 149 specifically, you will have to read up 148 lines using `fgets` in a loop, then read the line using `fgetss`

Comment: its a .php file and i am trying to run this file in my local wamp server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation, `fgetss` will read `length` bytes for the current line. So `fgetss($myfile,149,"<td>,</td>")` will read 149 bytes on the first line.

You could try (quick and dirty):

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("1.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
for ($i = 0; $i < 149; $i++) fgets($myfile);
echo fgetss($myfile, 4096, "<td>,</td>");
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Side note, you want to read file, so replace `a+` with `r` in your `fopen` call

Answer (score 0):

The function **fgetss()** the second parameter informs the amount of bytes that will be returned in the line and not the specific line that you want to pick up.

One way to get a specific line from a file, is by using a function:

```
<?php

function get_line($arq,$linha)
{
 $arquivo = file($arq);
 $y = $linha - 1;
 $x = print $arquivo[$y];
 return $x;
}
get_line("1.txt",149);
?>
```